# Are there heuristics that play Klondike Solitaire well?

Tags: reference-request, heuristics, games-of-chance, card-games

Are there heuristics that play [Klondike Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)) well?

I know there are some good **exhaustive search solvers** for [Klondike Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)). The best one that I know of is **Solvitaire** (2019) which uses DFS, (see [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.12314), [code](https://github.com/thecharlieblake/Solvitaire)).

I searched the web for heuristics that plays as a human would play, with no backwards moves, however, I found only one.  In that paper, they report on a win-rate of **13.05%**.  In comparison, human experts reach 36.6% win-rate in *[thoughtful solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)#Probability_of_winning)* which is [Klondike Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire)) where the location of all the cards is known. Source: [Solitaire: Man Versus Machine (2005)](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/solitaire.pdf).

**Are there any other published heuristics for [Klondike Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_(solitaire))?**

When determining if a heuristic is interesting, I would consider its win-rate and the similarity to how humans are playing.

Comment: Does [The complexity of Solitaire](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2009.08.027) interest you?

Comment: While this paper is interesting, my interest in Solitaire is from a practical point of view.  I wish to estimate the difficulty of different setups.  One way is by getting the output of a DFS solver and the solution of an ID-DFS optimal-solution solver.  Second way is to examinee the win-rate of heuristics.  The third option is to examinee the win-rate of human.